# Allowing multiple versions of a transitive gradle dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to use a gradle dependency which includes `jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1`. However, I have another dependency which includes `jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3`.

v3 includes breaking changes, primarily a package rename from `javax` to `jakarta` so each dependency needs to exact bind-api version it links to function - otherwise ClassNotFound errors are thrown.

In the dependency graph, gradle is resolving v3 to 2.3.3: `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1 -> 2.3.3`.

I can't seem to find any way to resolve this (module resolution, etc).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: One of your dependencies needs version 3.0.1, the other one needs version 2.3.3?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: That won't work, you can only install one version of each dependency. You'll need to up- or downgrade one of you dependencies so both work with 2.3.3 or both work with 3.0.1.

Comment: I have never used it personally, but perhaps https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/#filtering-relocation could help?

Answer (score 0):

You should imagine if we were able to create two files with the same name inside some folder. How should computer handle such situations with naming? How to determine which file consists of which info? What about users ?

Same applies to the dependencies. Their source and/or compiled byte code already contains classes full names (like hierarchy structure where it is located in the package)

The only one solution you can try - make changes in the lib to use needed version of dependency if it's open source and freely distributed, otherwise to wait official release of supported version

Comment: What about https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/#filtering-relocation – would it solve the problem?

Comment: I have never used it before. After looking through the docs seems like it is what OP is asking for.